# Basic understanding of Angular Http

Tags: angular, promise, observable, angular-http

I have read some articles about Angular's `Http` service, but still I cannot understand some things:

1. what does `http.get('some/string/')` return?
2. what does `http.get('some/string/').map` return? If `map` does not return an actual result of `http` request, what for do I need to use it?
3. How can I get actual result of `http` request without using `map`, observables, `toPromise` etc.?
4. Can I just use `Promise`s without `toPromise`? If not, how can I use `toPromise`  to get actual result of `http` request?

Comment: You have asked too many questions in the question body here, which will make it hard to provide a clear answer.  Also, the majority of your questions are answered in the [official documentation for `http`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html), which would make answers here just re-interpretations of the documentation anyway.  You should try to clarify what you have *actually tried*, and the challenges you are having with your attempts.

Comment: Actually, I did not find answers to these questions in documentation.

Comment: Http revolves around Observables. Learn to use and embrace them if you are want to use Angular

Comment: Odd, because I found *all* of them....  except you probably won't find `Promices` or `.toPromice`;  Accurate spelling is **very important** to bug free programming.

Comment: 1 and 2 you can just run them and find out. For 3 and 4a, you can't. 4b you can look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `http.get(url)` returns an `Observable` which you can use with none or any of the RxJS operators (eg `map`, `filter` etc - see [RxJs docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html))

**EDIT - as of Angular 4.3 the Http module assumes JSON as deafult so the map(res=>res.json()) call no longer needed!**

2) `http.get(url).map()` will return a mapped (transformed) `Observable`, potentially wrapping a different type, eg `Observable<string>`. The exact type depends on the function inside your `map` call. Often in Angular 2/4, this function is used to map a response to a javascript object using the `.json()` method:

`this.http.get(url).map(response => response.json())`

which will give you an `Observable` wrapping the JS object, eg something like 
`{user: 'Fred', balance: 65535}`.
To actually 'use' this object/response, you must SUBSCRIBE to the Observable, usually in the calling component (although possibly in the service), and in the subscribe callback you can do what you want with the actual response data, eg log it, pass it to other functions, store as a class member etc:

```
http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(resObject => {
   console.log(resObject);
   this.user = resObject.user;
   this.balance = resObject.balance;
});
```

Only when subscribe is called is the http request actually made... this is the nature of Rx!

3) You can't, you HAVE to subscribe to the observable. The response from an http call is by nature ASYNCHRONOUS and cannot be simply transformed in synchronous code - you can't just write, e.g.

`this.user = http.get(url).fromObservable()` as there is no guarantee the server has responded and provided something to convert and use in synchronous code. In addition, the nature of an observable here is that unless it is subscribed to, the observable will not do anything!

4) You can transform an observable to a promise (although I would avoid it unless you reeeeally love promises as observable are MUCH more powerful) and use `.then` if you like...

Comment: Thanks. However, still it not completely clear, what for `map` has to be used right after `http.get()`. Why do I have to map a response to json, if in the end I still get Observable, not a json object after a call to `map`.

Comment: I have made an edit - you don't HAVE to make the map call, but if the server response is not in json format then you'll have to deal with that fact elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Claies that you should read the docs, however, I can also understand it could be a bit difficult at first.

`Http.get()` call will return an `Observable` which you can subscribe to, to make it actually work.

Observables has 150~ methods, like map, flatMap, filter, scan and what not which you can think of them as Array methods.

When you call each of those methods, what you get back is another observable , so it's a chain :

```
   let firstThing = Observable
   let secondThing = firstThing.doSomething()
   let thirdThing  = secondThing.doSomethingElse()
```

could be :

```
    let thirdThing =   firstThing.domeSomething().doSomethingElse();
```

It's called chaining and you had them in JQuery as well :

```
element.find(blah).addClass(bllaah).removeClass().find() ....
```

Last but not least, all the observables are cold ( lazy), meaning that unless you subscribe to them, the whole chain is't doing anything.

Having said that,

This is not gonna run `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` until someone subscribe to them.

```
    let thirdThing =   firstThing.domeSomething().doSomethingElse();
```

so to make em work :

```
        thirdThing.subscribe(callback);
```

So , you can't use `http methods` without subscribing to them.